# JPA Criteria API missing

Tags: jpa, criteria

I'm building application that uses JPA, and I want to use Criteria API as described http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/jpa_overview_criteria.html. More precisely this part:

```
EntityManager em = ... ; 
CriteriaBuilder queryBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery qdef = queryBuilder.createCriteriaQuery();
```

The problem is that there is no `getCriteriaBuilder()` method in my `EntityManager` and also `CriteriaBuilder` and `CriteriaQuery` cannot be found in the `persistance-api-1.0.jar`

What am I missing? As I'm using a wrong jar? Mine is from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/

Regrads,
Oleksandr

Answer (score 5):

Criteria is in JPA2, and you have a jar for JPA1. There is no "official" JPA2.jar yet, but there is an Apache2 licensed one from Apache
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.0-PFD2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JBoss 4.2.3 GA and it is working fine:

```
import javax.persistence.criteria;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

   CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
```