# i added jpa2 jar file to library, but still can't find getCriteriaBuilder method

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

i am using hibernate jpa, i can use jpql query successfully but i can't use criteria api. i have read [JPA Criteria API missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081073/jpa-criteria-api-missing) and [jar file for JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243147/jar-file-for-jpa-2-0), i added hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final file to library and still can't find getCriteriaBuilder() method. Please help me

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

method(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistenceunit");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
}
```

i'm using these libraries:
My hibernate library files: antlr-2.7.6.jar, asm.jar, asm-attrs.jar, cglib-2.1.3.jar, commons-collections-2.1.1.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, ehcache-1.2.3.jar, ejb3-persistence.jar, hibernate3.jar, hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations.jar, hibernate-entitymanager.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar, hibernate-tools.jar, javassist.jar, jdbc2_0-stdext.jar, jta.jar, jtidy-r8-20060801.jar. Which could cause this ?

Also other libraries: jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar, JSTL 1.1 - standard.jar, JSTL 1.1 - jstl.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-digester3-3.0.jar and prettyfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you removed JPA 1.0 libraries when you added ones for 2.0? If not, then it looks like EntityManager is picked from there. That's why first point where it fails is method that was introduced in JPA 2.

Comment: My hibernate library files: antlr-2.7.6.jar, asm.jar, asm-attrs.jar, cglib-2.1.3.jar, commons-collections-2.1.1.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, ehcache-1.2.3.jar, ejb3-persistence.jar, hibernate3.jar, hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations.jar, hibernate-entitymanager.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar, hibernate-tools.jar, javassist.jar, jdbc2_0-stdext.jar, jta.jar, jtidy-r8-20060801.jar. Which could cause this ? Also other libraries: jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar, JSTL 1.1 - standard.jar, JSTL 1.1 - jstl.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-digester3-3.0.jar & prettyfaces

Comment: ejb3-persistence.jar is likely source for this problem, because it is one that contains EntityManager.class. Next step Is probably to remove those libraries that belong to your former version of Hibernate.

Comment: i removed ejb3-persistence.jar and all hibernate libraries and added these hibernate-distribution-3.6.7.Final jar files: antlr-2.7.6.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, hibernate3.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar, javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar, jta-1.1.jar, slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar. now my project can find getCriteriaBuilder method, but when the project is running, this error occured: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder()Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder; The stack trace did not have any message more than that one.